# Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Tags: java, html, ajax, primefaces, drop-down-menu

Im trying to call a function on selection of a value from dropdown. Heres my code:

```
<h:form id="frmUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">  

       <p:column><h:outputText value="Select Team: " /></p:column>
        <p:column>
                #{' '}
                <h:selectOneMenu required="true" id="ddlTeam" value="#{telesalesUpload.selectTeam}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Dunning Team" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="SAVD Team"  />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                #{' '}
         <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" listener="#{telesalesUpload.UpdateTeam}" /> 

        </p:column>

<h:outputText value="Note: first row will be skipped as header row!" />  
<p:fileUpload  fileUploadListener="#{telesalesUpload.handleFileUpload}"  
        process = "ddlTeam" 
        auto="true"
        mode="advanced"
        update="messages,:frmData"  
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|jpe?g|png)$/"/>  
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

But i get this error :  Unable to attach  to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must put `<p:ajax>` inside `<p:selectOneMenu>`.

```
<p:column>
     #{' '}
     <p:selectOneMenu required="true" id="ddlTeam" value="#{telesalesUpload.selectTeam}">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Dunning Team" />
         <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="SAVD Team"  />
         <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" listener="#{telesalesUpload.UpdateTeam}" /> 
     </p:selectOneMenu>
     #{' '}
</p:column>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue Pellizon. I figured it out just now and was about to answer it. But you gave it, so thanks :D